# Bootstrap 4 table vertical align middle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

Im trying to **vertically center** the content of this table with `align-middle` class but it doesn´t work. How can I make it works?

```css
tr, td, p, a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-borderless">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary">LoremIpsum:</p>
         </td>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>,
            <a href="#">dolor sit amet</a>,
            <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a>,
            <a href="#">elit ultricies</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary">Magna morbi sociis:</p>
         </td>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <a href="#">Link</a>, 
            <a href="#">Link</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: seems to work fine: https://www.bootply.com/Aq8YVJ0a7x it may not be totally centered as you have use a p tag which has margin on it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [remove the margin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/) from the paragraphs (`my-0`) if you want the table cells to appear vertically aligned..

```
<td class="align-middle">
    <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary my-0">LoremIpsum:</p>
</td>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/MIWKNo9GQs

Comment: Oh, thanks. Where can I find my-0 class in the documentation?

Comment: It's a spacing util: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/

Comment: But `my-0` class does not appear in that page.

Comment: @SilverSurfer you will not find it explicitely, you need to build it alone based on the rule described on that page `{property}{sides}-{size}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, last question, do you think it has any relevance semantically the p tag? I would be better a span?

Comment: @SilverSurfer you don't have a lot of content so yes you can instead use span to avoid the margin issue. I don't think there will be a difference in the semantic

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `align-middle` class. It's the default margin of the paragraphs who is interrupting your alignment. Just replace the paragraph into an `<span>` and you're done!

```css
tr, td, p, a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-borderless">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <span class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary">LoremIpsum:</span>
         </td>
         <td>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>,
            <a href="#">dolor sit amet</a>,
            <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a>,
            <a href="#">elit ultricies</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <span class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary">Magna morbi sociis:</span>
         </td>
         <td>
            <a href="#">Link</a>, 
            <a href="#">Link</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

hope this helps.. Added `margin:0 !important` for p tag

```css
tr, td, p, a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
p{margin:0 !important}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-borderless">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary">LoremIpsum:</p>
         </td>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>,
            <a href="#">dolor sit amet</a>,
            <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a>,
            <a href="#">elit ultricies</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic text-secondary">Magna morbi sociis:</p>
         </td>
         <td class="align-middle">
            <a href="#">Link</a>, 
            <a href="#">Link</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```